# StringBuilder growing over 85k and moving to LOH?

Tags: .net, clr, large-object-heap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does StringBuilder's capacity change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547827/how-does-stringbuilders-capacity-change)

Let's say a StringBuilder is allocated and then it grows to over 85k, will it get moved over to the Large Object Heap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StringBuilder` doesn't "grow".

In pre-4.0 SB, it simply allocated a new bigger buffer and copied the content from the old to the new. So in the end yes, the internal buffer was moved to LOH. The SB object not, because it's very small (to make it simple, it could have been simply a reference to the buffer and the length of the string in the buffer. It was a little more complex because it implemented copy-on-write after using the `ToString` method. So the `ToString` method made the buffer read-only and returned it as a string, and any other write to the SB duplicated the buffer).

In 4.0 SB uses something like a linked list of buffers (it's called a "rope"), and they are always small enough not to go to LOH.

Comment: "Always small enough not to go to LOH." Is this true even if I `Append` a string that's a megabyte in size?

Comment: @Jim You are right. The `Append` will add zero or one blocks, so the added block will be as much big as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `StringBuilder` itself won't be allocated on the LOH, but its internal string buffer will be. The allocator doesn't know anything about what objects are allocating its data. It just knows that an allocation larger than some maximum size will go to the LOH.

Comment: This is true for .NET versions before 4.0. From versions 4 another strategy is used where the internal buffer is stringed together from multiple buffers, avoiding the internal buffer being moved to LOH.

Comment: @driis: Thanks. I'll have to go look at the `StringBuilder` source.