# String Builder (.NET4.0+) initialising capacity

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have read that internal implementation of StringBuilder has changed significantly in .NET4.0:
[StringBuilder growing over 85k and moving to LOH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640162/stringbuilder-growing-over-85k-and-moving-to-loh)
[How does StringBuilder's capacity change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547827/how-does-stringbuilders-capacity-change)

What is the implication of these changes for specifying capacity during SB creation?
Is it still of benefit to do this?

```
Dim BigString As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500000)
For Each ...
    BigString.Append("some text")
Next
```

Comment: There is no one correct answer, the balance between speed and memory usage is forever a programmer's choice.  If the Capacity is less than 85,000 then always.  If it is between 85,000 and about a million then you might favor the rope behavior.  Which *is* slower, but not by much, ballpark it at about 10%.  If is more than a million then the ropes start to slam the gen#0 heap too heavy and causes other objects to get promoted too early so do specify it again.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Please clarify rope behaviour. Does SB always use ropes OR are they only used to grow capacity above the initial size? In the example above by specifying a large capacity do I get 500000 / 8000 ropes or one contiguous chunk of memory?

Comment: I assumed that you already knew.  If you specify the Capacity, and guess correctly, then there's only *one* allocation for the buffer.  No ropes.  Which is why it is faster.  And why it gets allocated in the LOH if Capacity is larger than 85,000

Comment: @Hans Passant, thanks for taking the time to respond. I have looked around before posting, but did not find anything re internals of SB (my .NET skill level is not high enough to answer this question by reading http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,cce7345d4e194923) . I would appreciate if you can provide me with a link (or a "search term" to use). I think you should also post all of the above as an answer.